# MSDeploy Error_Connection_Terminated while trying to deploy website

Tags: c#, iis, msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

I have been getting the error "Error_Connection_Terminated" when trying to deploy a site to my localhost from the developer command prompt using MSDeploy and I am at the end of my rope trying to figure out whats causing it, the error is pretty ambiguous as to what the problem actually is. I've set privileges for the deploy folder correctly and I have restarted the Web Deployment Agent Service numerous times in the services window. I have gone over many solution's already posted on the net but to no avail as none of them deal with using the developer command prompt and instead only offer solution's by using visual studio itself.

Would anyone with experience with MSDeploy or IIS, be able to shed some light or advise on how to solve this.

the error states "Error_Connection_Terminated Error: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 550.
Error count: 1."

[image]

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem and was able to successfully deploy after closing [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on the machine on which I was running MSDeploy.

This would fit with [Marcello's findings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30573415/81595) - I assume that he had Fiddler open and that he closed it when he rebooted.

Comment: +1  Exactly the same error message ("results. Line 1, position 550"). Solved by closing Fiddler. Mark as correct answer?

Comment: In my case Fiddler was causing the troubles, too (as Scott found out)

Comment: Also solved the same issue by closing Fiddler. Thank you!

Comment: definitely network-related. I was in a public library (which probably has a proxy server or some such), tethered it to my phone instead and it worked fine.

Comment: This was also my issue. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well I came across the same issue like about a week ago and for all those who the solutions aforementioned didn't work out (because there might be many reasons behind this error) I figured out what was happening.

I tried everything the others above mentioned but didn't work since I don't use Fiddler, all Web deploy services were up and running as expected, Web publish profiles were working well before, and web deploy port was open.

After searching around what the cause was being and turned the firewall off because I wanted to make sure there was no application blocking involved. It turns out that antivirus was causing the _ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED error.

Now I want to clearly state that many of you would say that was probably one of the first things to check but an admin installed it and I didn't know about it. Finally, I uninstalled the antivirus and everything went back to normal.

I guess that everyone agrees on this: Microsoft isn't very informative/specific about error's causes.

Comment: Same for me! I spend hours if not day reinstalling / reinstalling combos of webdeploy 3.6 et 4 to no avail. I even reinstalled the whole VS 2017 etc. And I remembered having a some Eset Nod antivirus in the backgound... I deinstalled it, and it works.
Note that I had it working at some point, before getting this same error. Since I hadn't made much modification to the system, let alone touched the antivirus, I thought the culprit couldn't be it.

Comment: Follow up on my previous comment : it doesn't work anymore. WTF is going on ? Why such inpredictability ? It makes no sense. I see only one solution here : reinstall windows and all my programs, again...

Comment: I especially like how the error message states "Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED" yet the page doesn't even mention ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.  One of these days I'll click on a Microsoft "help" page only to see a giant ASCII art middle finger

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. A reboot of my developer machine solved the problem (whereas rebooting the deployment server (a test machine), reinstalling msdeploy, using a different account and other solutions did not help...).

Answer (score 1):

Some help for others that have the same error code:
If you are using the UI from Visual Studio, do not enter the http:// prefix on the server input (after all, the e.g. doesn't have it).  I was really confused, because I have a saved profile WITH http:// and that one works.
Note: My setup is Visual Studio 2013 for Web w/ Update 4
Maybe this started after installing update 4 which i did recently.

Update (after being downvoted):  Here are some additional tips:

- Ensure that Management Services is installed from the "Turn on and off
  features".  This is part of the IIS configuration.
- Ensure that "Web Management Service" is started.  After installing the feature, its set to manual and not started.
- Ensure that the "Web Deploy Agent Service" is started.
- Ensure TCP port 8172 incoming is open on the server

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure traffic is allowed to 192.229.211.108:80 Fiddler was showing 502 bad gateways to digicert.com hosts when trying to negotiate TLS to our app service. After the firewall block was removed the Fiddler log turned into a series of 200's to our app service IP address as expected and the error stopped.