# Publish fails - can't understand what to do

Tags: azure-functions

VS2017 15.9.13 and Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools 15.10.2059.23219

Project builds but always fails to publish with these errors. Is this a bug or something I'm doing? This is a vanilla File New HTTP function - I haven't changed anything.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error : Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.) [C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error :  [C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error : Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED. [C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(139,5): error : Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 550. [C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1.csproj]


Find all ""error"", Find Results 1, Current Document
  (1084):1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
  (1097):1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\Release\netstandard2.0\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bin\Release\netstandard2.0\')).
  (1098):1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\obj\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\obj\')).
  (1099):1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('obj\Release\netstandard2.0\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('obj\Release\netstandard2.0\')).
  (1100):1>  Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InitialMSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)' != '' And '$(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)' != '$(_InitialMSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)' ) was evaluated as ( 'C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\obj\' != '' And 'C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\obj\' != 'C:\Users\adm_someuser\source\repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\obj\' ).
  Matching lines: 5
```

csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.13" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What does your FunctionApp1.csproj look like?

Comment: added csproj above

Comment: Could you have Fiddler open on the machine? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31456569/3516125

Comment: Or Antivirus? See that same issue as above for someone else that hit this with antivirus running.